# Find the nearest value in an array to the given value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to retrieve the nearest value from the array list for the given value.

I tried to retrieve the nearest value, but I'm having trouble with the for loop I am using.

```
def get_total_price_iot(self):
    """calculate the price """


    value = 2.5
    constants = [2,3,4,5]

    for x in range(len(constants)):
      if(value<constants[0]):
           print('Nearest Value ',constants[0])

      elif(value>=constants[x] and value<=constants[x+1]):
          midValue = (constants[x] + constants[x + 1]) / 2

          if (midValue <= value):
              midValue = constants[x + 1];
              print("Nearest midGirth ", midValue)
          elif (midValue > value):
              midValue = constants[x]
              print("Nearest value ", midValue)


      else:
          print('Nearest value ',constants[len(constants)-1])
```

My expected result is `3`, but I'm getting `4` as output instead.

Here is my output:

```
Nearest midGirth  3
Nearest value  5
Nearest value  5
Nearest value  5
```

Comment: Nearest value can be 2 also?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added why 2 is not acceptable.

Comment: As in normal maths we are rounding 2.5 in to 3.

Comment: Are your constants always sorted?

Comment: Rounding up and nearest are two different things, that changes the scope of the question entirely :(

Comment: Yes my constants are always sorted @MarkMeyer

Comment: I want the nearest value not the rounding value.But as 2.5 is in the middle I assume the nearest one is 3

Comment: Well both are equally closer, but if the value was 2.1, would the answer for you be 2 or 3 @Samasha ?

Comment: It should be 2 @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: Then correct me if I am wrong, but if the values are close by like 2 and 3 for 2.5, you want the higher value i.e 3, otherwise  if you want the closest value, like 2 for 2.1 is that right @Samasha ? If yes, I will fix my answer to consider both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, you want to do something like this:

```
value = 2.5
constants = [2,3,4,5]

for x in range(len(constants)):
  if(value<constants[0]):
       print('Nearest Value ',constants[0])
       break

  elif(value>=constants[x] and value<=constants[x+1]):
      midValue = (constants[x] + constants[x + 1]) / 2

      if (midValue <= value):
          midValue = constants[x + 1];
          print("Nearest midGirth ", midValue)
          break
      elif (midValue > value):
          midValue = constants[x]
          print("Nearest value ", midValue)
          break
  else:
      print('Nearest value ',constants[len(constants)-1])
      break
```

Notice I am using `break`s in between.

Output:

```
Nearest midGirth  3
```

Also I am confused with:

> But I'm getting 4 output. I want to avoid it

I guess you want to display only: `Nearest midGirth  3`.

Comment: Oh yes.Thank you a lot. Because of missing break statements I suffered to get the correct output.

Comment: Also, @Devesh posted a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are guaranteed that the input list is an integer, just convert value to it's ceiling by `math.ceil` and compare number with value

```
import math

value = 2.5
constants = [2,3,4,5]

for item in constants:
    if item == math.ceil(value):
        print(item)
```

The answer will be `3` here

An optimized approach is to calculate a `difference` array, i.e. difference between value and each element, sort it and return the `2nd element+value`

```
def get_nearest(value, constants):

    #Calculate the difference array between value and each element in constants
    diffs = [item-value for item in constants]

    #Sort it
    diffs = sorted(diffs)

    #Return the second element+value
    return diffs[1]+value
```

The outputs will be

```
print(get_nearest(2.5, [2,3,4,5]))
#3.0
print(get_nearest(2.5, [2,13,4,5]))
#4.0
print(get_nearest(2.1, [2,13,4,5]))
#4.0
```

Comment: What if `constants = [2,13,4,5]`?

Comment: Or if the value is 2.1

Comment: Coming up with the solutions for those! Hold on sirs!

Comment: This is much easier.Thanks

Comment: Updated with a difference solution @MarkMeyer Austin! Check if this makes sense?

Comment: Great! Glad to be of help @Samasha If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just find the min of the difference using the `key` of the `min` function. In the case of ties Python 3's [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) will return the first value encountered. Since your constants are sorted you can look through them in reverse to get the effect of rounding up:

```
value = 2.5
constants = [2,3,4,5]

# find the min of the differences between value and constants
# ties will find the largest value
min(reversed(constants), key = lambda x: abs(x-value))

# Result:  3
```

Answer (score 0):

use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([2,3,4,5])
a[np.abs((a-value)).argmin()]
```

it will outpout 2 for value=2.5 because it's standard rounding. if you need nonstandard 2.5->3 rounding round value using   decimals module